# Get amount of data transferred during query refresh

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Is there a way to track the amount of data transferred during query refresh?
The size is shown in the 'Queries' pane very briefly (depending on the wait):

[image]

The only solution I can think of is saving the pure output to CSV and measuring the filesize.
Is there a more direct, less cumbersome way?

The **main reason behind this** is that I want to see:
1: If the size could cause issues to users with slow connections
2: The effect of my optimisation attempts

Please note that this would **ideally be source-agnostic**, however my primary focus are SharePoint lists & files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that, but you could check the file size by connecting the the sharepoint folder, then drilling into the Attributes record and grabbing the Size record

See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/sharepointfolder

or
https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/get-data-from-onedrive-or-sharepoint-with-power-query

[image]

sample for desktop version, but not sharepoint

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\temp\"),
#"C:\intraday\_mydata csv" = Source{[#"Folder Path"="C:\temp\",Name="mydata.csv"]}[Attributes],
Size = #"C:\temp\_mydata csv"[Size]
in Size
```

[image]